# SQL : return all rows that contain particular value more than once

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the following contents:

```
store        Qty
----
store1       1
store2       2
store1       3
store2       2
```

I want to output this:

```
------------
store     Qty
store2    2(value '2' occurs 2 times)
store1    0(value '2' occurs 0 times)
```

I want to return occurrence of column `Qty` with value '2' (with how many times it occured) in descending order.

Comment: Woops, removing "table" was a mistake, but diff shows I modified plenty of other things (quantities etc.), which I didn't. Was that a bug, or simultaneous edit that was not recorded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation (that is, using a `case` statement with an aggregation function):

```
select store, sum(case when Qty = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as Qty
from table t
group by store;
```

Comment: Thanks , thats it . short and Clear

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.store, COUNT(QTY) AS QTY2
FROM TABLE T
WHERE t.QTY = 2
GROUP BY t.store
ORDER BY COUNT(QTY) DESC
```

This should work. It will provide a count of how many 2's are present grouped by store and show the stores in descending order based on the number of 2's present.